# VBA copy-paste from last to first empty cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

First of all I do know that this question was already asked, but I am not very good at vba, so I kindly ask for your help, because I couldn't implement solutions I've found..

So I have to lists "alfa" and "beta". I need to copy range B2:E2 until the empty B.
Then copy it to the first empty row in column B.

The last and the first empty will always be different..

would appreciate your help very much!

Comment: When asking questions you should include the code that you have tried, the aim of this site is to provide guidance / help though without seeing your current effort its pretty hard to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Kopy()
    Dim N As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r1 = Range("B2:E" & N)
    Set r2 = Range("B" & (N + 1))
    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

We only need to specify a **single cell** in the destination range.
Formats as well as values will be copied.